# Post Request is not working with self signed SSL

Tags: java, ssl, https, http-post, angular8

Technology Stack Used

- Angular 8 (front-end)
- Java Jersey (back-end)

All thing are working fine, before a self signed certificate is applies to the URL. I googled it, read many post in stack overflow also, but nothing works for me or I didn't understand what they are trying to say. So If any one can help please ..?

Below is the scenario.
All thing is working with HTTP

- Then for compliance we had to use HTTPS so we got the self signed SSL certificate and then POST request is stop working in chrome browser.
- In Postman with below is setting, I'm getting the error
  [postman setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbTf8.png)

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz8Ti.png)

with this setting disabled it work just fine in postman.

- In ARC POST request is working fine with the HTTPS URL
- In firefox it is all different
  [first warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mMKF.png)
  then I continue and site open, but can't do any POST request, same as chrome browser.

Please help me with this.

Comment: If you need to verify the certificate, you will need to add it to the client's trust store. That depends on where your application is getting the trust store.

Answer (score 0):

Just did some change's in tomcat config file and it works.